# How to use setError() in android TextInputLayout so that the respective error is shown?

Tags: android, material-design

[image: For example i want that the email textInputLayout should only show when i am working with email,but here all are showing and conform password error is not showing]

I have written below the code. **Firstly**, I want to see error of only one `TextInputLayout` I am working with. **Secondly**, the error for conform password isn't showing, what I can do to solve this?

```
public class DoctorSignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView tvSubmit;
EditText etEmailId, etPassword, etCPassword, etMobile;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
TextInputLayout tilEmailId,tilPassword,tilCPassword,tilMobile;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_signup);

    //initialize view controls

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    etEmailId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailId);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etCPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCPassword);
    etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMobile);

    tvSubmit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSubmit);

    tilEmailId= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.tilEmailId);
    tilPassword= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.tilPassword);
    tilCPassword= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.tilCPassword);
    tilMobile= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.tilMobile);

    //event handling

    tvSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);


    etEmailId.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(DoctorSignUp.this));
    etPassword.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(DoctorSignUp.this));
    etCPassword.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(DoctorSignUp.this));
    etMobile.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(DoctorSignUp.this));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    registerUser();

}

private void registerUser() {

    String email = etEmailId.getText().toString();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User,Please wait..");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed To Register The User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    public MyTextWatcher(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        validateEmail();
        validatePasswword();
        validateConformPassword();
        validateMobile();


    }

    private void validateConformPassword() {

        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        String cpassword=etCPassword.getText().toString();

        if(!password.equals(cpassword)){
            tilCPassword.setError("Please enter the same password again");
        }
        else
            tilCPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);


    }


    private void validateMobile() {
        String mobile = etMobile.getText().toString();

        if(mobile.length()<10) {
            tilMobile.setError("Enter a valid mobile no.");
        }

        else
            tilMobile.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    private void validatePasswword() {

        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        if (password.length() <6){
            tilPassword.setError("Password must be of 6 characters atleast");
        }
        else
            tilPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    private void validateEmail() {

        String email = etEmailId.getText().toString();

        if(!email.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+")){
            tilEmailId.setError("Please enter valid email id");
        }
        else
            tilEmailId.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Type of Method .

```
 public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;
        enteredEmailId = mEmail.getText().toString();
        enteredPassword = mPassword.getText().toString();
        if (enteredEmailId.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(enteredEmailId).matches()) {
            mEmail.setError("Please Enter Valid Email Address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            mEmail.setError(null);
        }
        if (enteredPassword.isEmpty() || enteredPassword.length() < 4 || enteredPassword.length() > 10) {
            mPassword.setError("Password should be between 4 to 10 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            mPassword.setError(null);
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

> **you can Validate All Text As you Wish Take all in one**

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    public MyTextWatcher(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {



     switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.etEmailId:


        validateEmail();

    break;

    case R.id.etPassword:


    validatePasswword();

    break;

    case R.id.etCPassword:


       validatePasswword();
       validateConformPassword();

    break;

    case R.id.etMobile:


       validateMobile();

    break;






    }




    }
```

> Used the equalsIgnoreCase to match string

```
    private void validateConformPassword() {

    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    String cpassword=etCPassword.getText().toString();

    if(!password.equalsIgnoreCase(cpassword)){
        tilCPassword.setError("Please enter the same password again");
    }
    else
        tilCPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);


}
```

Comment: Thankx a lot sir,really helpful.